# console.log an expression before/without evaluation

Tags: javascript, console

Given a statement such as `let boolVal = 1 < 2`, is there a way to console log the actual expression, i.e. `1 < 2` *not* the `true` result?

```js
let boolVal = 1 < 2;
console.log(boolVal)            // logs out the boolean result
console.log(boolVal.toString()) // logs out the boolean result as a string

/* is there a way to get just
'1 < 2'
itself to be logged out? */
```

Comment: The answer is no

Comment: JavaScript is an imperative language, which means that your expression is evaluated before the assignment to the variable takes place. It literally does not exist as a thing by the time that `let` statement is done.

Comment: you want it to be genric?

Comment: Not really. The variable is boolean. It has no information what how it was assigned.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Kristjan Kica - I was trying to write a function that could take an array of simple, boolean evaluation criteria and log both the criteria and the result, e.g. `const tests = [ 1< 2, 1 === '1', 1>2, 0]` processed to something like `true: 1<2`, `true: 1==='1'`, `false: 1>2`, `false: 0`.  I was trying to ensure the simplest syntax as possible, so many of the suggested answers make the criteria input more complicated than desired, not to mention needing to account for the different comparisons a priori.

Comment: In addition, I'm passing in variable names, and those variable names have a clear meaning where the values don't.  For example `7777 > 7665` isn't as clear as something like `userAge > legalAge`.  So at this point, I'm actually considering the reverse, and having the expressions sent in as strings, that can be logged out or run with `eval` (which I'm really not a fan of).

Comment: See my answer and tell me if it suits your needs

Comment: Yeah. Thats in my answer. Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your response in the comment section, I see you need a generic solution with different operands.
The simplest solution I can think of is by using eval.

1- Create an array of strings array[]. You could  creare a string. "" +expression.
2- console.log(array[index]+ eval(array[index]) )

Although i would not recommend. Eval is bad for both performance and security.
Another workaround is to make a connection for the results and for string you create from the first step. Like 2 arrays or create objects with 2 attributes. {value:, expression}.
You can print them accourdingly when you print the variable.

Comment: This is actually my fallback solution, although I was trying to avoid it precisely because of the inherent problems with `eval`.

Comment: I had actually considered the string and expression route. I'm not sure if there are any actual benefits, but it does require a bit more effort on the user's end, and could easily get out of sync which could cause more problems.  And the users are still sending in code to be evaulated, so  eval isn't significantly more dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by making a custom function:

```js
function printExpression(x,y){
  console.log( (x<y?x:y) + " < " + (x<y?y:x));
}
printExpression(1,2);
printExpression(4,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function that makes the comparison, and log both the result of that function and the function itself.

```js
function boolValComparer(val1, val2) {
  console.log(val1, '<', val2); // logs the boolean comparison as string with parameters
  return val1 < val2;
}
let boolVal = boolValComparer(1, 2);
console.log(boolVal)            // logs out the boolean result
console.log(boolValComparer)    // logs out the comparer function as a string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let boolVal = 1 < 2;
```

You cant log **1 < 2** directly because they are compared and stored in boolVal. What you can do is a workaround.

Store **1** and **2** in variables var1 and var2.

```
let boolVal = var1 < var2

if boolVal:
    console.log(var1 + "<" + var2)
else:
    console.log(var1 + ">" + var2)
```